# python pdf extract image is extracting 2 images instead of one image(black background and white background

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python fitz module I am trying to extract images from pdf file, its extracting images correctly for most of the pdf files but for some pdf files its not working properly.
In pdf page only one image is there but while extracting its extracting multiple images and text is distributed in black background image and white background image( one image data is divided into 3 images), below is the code and pdf ad gray images

```
import fitz
from PIL import Image

# open the file
pdf_file = fitz.open("image path")

# iterate over PDF pages
for page_index in range(len(pdf_file)):

   # get the page itself
   page = pdf_file[page_index]
   image_list = page.get_images()

   # printing number of images found in this page
   if image_list:
    print(f"[+] Found a total of {len(image_list)} images in page {page_index}")
   else:
     print("[!] No images found on page", page_index)
   for image_index, image in enumerate(page.get_images(), start=0):
      xref = image[0]
      base_image = pdf_file.extract_image(xref)
      image_bytes = base_image["image"]
      image_ext = base_image["ext"]
      image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
      image.save(path to save)
```

Comment: How do you know the page was not constructed out of multiple images?

Comment: @Tim Roberts, i have the pdf file and if i copy it manually its single image, using code 3 images are downloaded and text is distributed in 3 images, one with black image with text and white image with text, if we merge 3 images it will have full text on it.

Comment: "if I copy it manually" -- What do you mean by that?

Comment: @tim Roberts, using online tools i am tested its downloaded as single image and using code also it shows the single image template but partial text is present in each image.

Comment: @tim Roberts, its working fine for RGB images ex:(642, 643, 24, 20, 8, 'DeviceRGB', '', 'X100', 'FlateDecode') but for gray images its not working properly. (4, 0, 1240, 1754, 8, 'DeviceGray', '', 'Obj4', 'FlateDecode')

Comment: Online tools that convert the pages to images are performing a VERY different task than PDF tools that extract the embedded images.  It's very common to construct a PDF page by overlaying several different images.  If you want the final page as a single image, then `fitz` is not the right tool.

Comment: @Tim Roberts,  pdf has only one image and its CCITTFaxDecode format. may be because of this fitz behaving differently